# Highchart column bar doesn't appear exactly

Tags: highcharts

I Use `datetime`  type in xAxis of Highchart and some of columns doesn't appear exactly in chart. For example in the below example you can see only a little part of first and last column. I don't know why.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/prince4prodigy/sc5hwtfz/)

What's the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by wrong order of points. You have an error in the console:

> Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15

In Highcharts, data should be sorted ascending by x-values, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/sc5hwtfz/2/

```
                {
                name: 'C1',
                    data: [
                            [Date.parse("04/26/2017" + " UTC"), 40],
                            [Date.parse("04/25/2017" + " UTC"), 143],
                            [Date.parse("04/24/2017" + " UTC"), 40],
                            [Date.parse("04/23/2017" + " UTC"), 30],
                            [Date.parse("04/22/2017" + " UTC"), 20],
                            [Date.parse("04/21/2017" + " UTC"), 20],
                    ].sort(function (a, b) { return a[0] - b[0]; })
                },
```